# iOS7: What is the best way to give the user the ability to choose between taking a photo and going to a photo gallery?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller

When a user clicks a certain button,I want him to have the ability to choose between taking a picture and choosing a picture from a gallery. As of right now it seems to be one or the other. Should I create two buttons for this or is there a better what to accomplish this? I am hoping a way to click a button and iOS will natively give the user the choice.

```
   -(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender

   {
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

// image picker needs a delegate,
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

// Place image picker on the screen
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Why are you initialising the picker controller twice? And why is it that you are checking for camera and presenting photo library as source if camera exists?

Comment: I dont really have time to explain, but lets just say it prevents a certain glitch from happening and will use this until I find a better alternative

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way would be to Create for example 2 buttons

- `UIBarButtonItem * choosePhotoBtn`
- `UIBarButtonItem * TakePhotoBtn`

Then call the same IBAction when pressing either button,  and put a condition in it to call the appropriate interface somehting like this:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIBarButtonItem *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

> But these are the best options, I like the UIAlertView the most to be honest

To be honest thats more clicks for the user, but again thats my opinion .
Here's how you can do it, Create your UIAlertView , then put a condition in its deleguate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *BtnSelected = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([BtnSelected isEqualToString:@"choosePhotoBtn"] {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I believe instead of doing it like this, you should try the Facebook style when you click on camera icon while writing posts. Check my answer with a link to Apple's own example code.

Answer (score 0):

When user press the button you can display UIAlertView or UIActionSheet, I would recommended UIAlertView for two button. And in the delegate method base on user selection you can make your logic to access camera or gallery.

Comment: I think an ActionSheet is more appropriate: `Use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with a set of alternatives for how to proceed with a given task`

Comment: But these are the best options, I like the UIAlertView the most to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options -

1. First show the pickerController with source type as photo library. Then there is a property in UIImagePickerController called cameraOverlayView. You can set it to a custom view with the button at the bottom that on click switches the pickerController source type to camera.
2. Read the photo library and present them for selection in a custom view with a button to launch camera which would use the UIImagePickerController with sourceType as camera.

More about overlayView - [[UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

Sample code project from Apple - [Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and Take Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)